# How to structure tsql query to handle multiple subtables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need help with how to write a SQL Server 2005 query to handle joining multiple subtables.  Here is my scenario:

Tables:

Customers

- Customer_PK

Orders

- Order_PK
- OrdersTypeA_FK
- OrdersTypeB_FK
- OrdersTypeC_FK
- Customer_FK

OrdersTypeA

- OrdersTypeA_PK
- Shipper_FK

OrdersTypeB

- OrdersTypeB_PK
- Shipper_FK

OrdersTypeC

- OrdersTypeC_PK
- Shipper_FK

Shippers

- Shipper_PK
- ShipperAddress_FK

ShipperAddress

- ShipperAddress_PK
- ShipperState

The Orders table has data that looks like the following:

```
Order_PK   OrdersTypeA_FK    OrdersTypeB_FK    OrdersTypeC_FK    Customer_FK
--------   --------------    --------------    --------------    -----------
1          1                 null              null              1
2          null              1                 null              2
3          null              null              1                 3
```

My issue is that I need to have the select join statement retrieve the ShipperAddress by finding the Shipper_FK from one of the three OrdersType tables.  The Orders table will only have one of the OrdersType FK per row.  The only thing I need to retreive from the OrdersType table is the Shipper_FK so that I can join to the ShipperAddress table.

So how does the join look???

```
select 
ShipperAddress.ShipperState 
from Customers
left join Orders on Orders.Customer_FK = Customers.Customer_PK

????????

left join Shippers on Shipper_PK = ??????.Shipper_FK
left join ShipperAddress on ShipperAddress.ShipperAddress_PK = Shippers.ShipperAddress_FK
```

I can't have a separate join down to ShipperAddress for each of the OrdersType tables.  This is a smaller sample of an issue that has many more tables at the OrdersType level.  The Shipper_FK is the same in each of the OrdersType tables.  I need to get at the Shipper_FK no matter what OrdersType table it came from to continue with the join statement.  How can that be done?

Comment: Why do you have three different order type columns (and then three different tables to go along with them)? What is so different about these order types that they need to be modeled separately?

Comment: This is just an example of the table structures I am dealing with.  For this example, think of OrderType_A as Mailing type, OrderType_B as Internet type, and OrderType_C as Phone type.  The table structure is set and cannot be changed.  The issue here is to figure out how to write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be fun to read, optimize and maintain...

```
SELECT sa.ShipperState  --, other columns surely
FROM dbo.Customers AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o 
ON o.Customer_FK = c.Customer_PK
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrdersTypeA AS oa
  ON oa.OrdersTypeA_PK = o.OrdersTypeA_FK
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrdersTypeB AS ob
  ON ob.OrdersTypeB_PK = o.OrdersTypeB_FK
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OrdersTypeC AS oc
  ON oc.OrdersTypeC_PK = o.OrdersTypeC_FK
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Shippers AS s
  ON s.Shipper_PK = COALESCE(oa.Shipper_FK, ob.Shipper_FK, oc.Shipper_FK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ShipperAddress AS sa
  ON s.ShipperAddress_FK = sa.ShipperAddress_PK;
```